# File missing from java.library.path in netbeans raspberry pi

Tags: java, rfid

I am trying to code for a motorola RFID reader using java and a Raspberry pi.

The error is:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rfidapi32jni in java.library.path

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
at com.mot.rfid.api3.API3Natives.<clinit>(API3Natives.java:2479)
at com.mot.rfid.api3.RFIDReader.connect(RFIDReader.java:375)
at rfidsample.RFIDBase.connectToReader(RFIDBase.java:175)
at rfidsample.ConnectionDlg.connectorMethod(ConnectionDlg.java:358)
at rfidsample.RFIDMainDlg.startReadButtonActionPerformed(RFIDMainDlg.java:944)
at rfidsample.RFIDMainDlg.access$700(RFIDMainDlg.java:39)
at rfidsample.RFIDMainDlg$8.actionPerformed(RFIDMainDlg.java:370)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
```

searching for the solution, looks like I need a RFIDAPI3_JNI_HOST.dll, I need this file I don't know if there is a way to use it on raspberry pi systems.

Comment: Doesn't Your raspberry pi use a Linux OS? If so, the library should be a ".so" file. And the program should be run on the raspberry. The binary librairies may not be available for PC.

Comment: ok I m understand but this missing file how can i found ?

Comment: if u have some idea About get files and library plz help

Comment: rfidapi32jni file missing in my program library how can i found ??

Comment: i will used java (netbeans) in raspberry pi and the error create that time

Comment: this error solve without this missing library in my project ?? if possible please reply ..

Comment: Sorry but i don't know the raspberry architecture and i don't own one. You can search the file with the linux command, find -name 'rfidapi32jni*'

Comment: ok ..thank u for this suggesion